# libgdx get rotated sprite coords points

Tags: java, mathematics, libgdx, sprites, rotation

I would like to get the position of each edge of a sprite when he has been rotated.

I have no idea how to do it, I made a image to explain it.

I would like to get **the X and Y position of each Red circles** please thanks you
.

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);
sprite.setRotation(-20);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To get the rotated sprites coordinate simply call the `getVertices()` method.

For example:
`sprite.getVertices()[SpriteBatch.X2]`

Gets you the X coordinates of the top left corner.

The same call but replacing `X<number>` with `Y<number>` gets you the Y coordinate.

The corner numbers go like this:

```
2-3
| |
1-4
```